# How to count a char

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a file as below and I want to count the number of times people mentioned others:

```
peter @amy 
tom @amy 
tom @amy 
peter @tom 
edwin @amy
amy @peter 
tom @john @peter
amy @edwin 
tom  @peter
peter @john 
peter @john
john  @tom?
edwin @john
edwin @amy 
amy @tom
```

I tried to use:

```
for line in fhand:
    if "@" in line:
        indexStart = line.find("@")
```

But I don't know what next. The expected output is:

```
tom 5
amy 3
edwin 3
peter 5
john 1
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please take the [tour]. "It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."

Comment: I just need some idea.

Comment: @Louis I will edit your question to take account of what was linked to you. It's not an issue, you'll just find that SO tends to be very matter-of-fact, which can feel uncomfortable for newer users but it means that your question is quicker/easier to understand for others in the future :). Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Option 1***
**`re.findall`** with **`collections.Counter`**

```
import re
from collections import Counter

with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = re.findall(r'(?m)^(\w+).*@.*$', f.read())
  print(Counter(data))

# Counter({'tom': 5, 'peter': 4, 'edwin': 3, 'amy': 3, 'john': 1})
```

**`regex`** explanation:

```
(?m)             # asserts multiline matching
^                # asserts position at the start of the line
(\w+)            # captures any word character in group 1 (this is the name you want)
.*               # Greedily matches any character besides line breaks
@                # Matches an @ symbol
.*               # Greedily matches any character besides line breaks
$                # Asserts position at end of line
```

---

If you actually need the *number of times they mention people* and not just the *number of lines in which they mention people*:

***Option 2***
Use **`collections.defaultdict`**:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
  dct = defaultdict(int)
  for line in f:
    dct[line.split()[0]] += line.count('@')
  print(dct)

# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'peter': 5, 'amy': 3, 'tom': 5, 'edwin': 3, 'john': 2})
```

***Option 3***
Live life on the edge with **`pandas`**:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('test.txt') as f:
  data = [i.split(' ', 1) for i in f.read().splitlines()]
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  print(df.groupby(0).sum()[1].str.count('@'))

# Result

0
amy      3
edwin    3
john     2
peter    5
tom      5
```